# DATETIME saving as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my sql code ive ran this same code a good amount of times and never had any issues with it but today or some reason it is.

```
mysqli_query($con, "
    INSERT INTO 'u_visits'
        ('ip_adress','dates')
    VALUES
        ('$ip',now())
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visits = visits + 1
");
mysqli_close($con);
```

Everything works fine except my dates row gets added as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

here is how i get the ip adress:

```
//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    //Is it a proxy address
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$ip = ip2long($ip);
```

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO id ,ip_adress,visits, dates

Comment: Those are your columns. Data types would be helpful.

Comment: What's your table schema? (i.e.: what type is the `dates` field?) Please update your question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
INSERT INTO `u_visits` (`ip_address`,`dates`) 
VALUES (
        '$ip', CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME() )
       )
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visits = visits +1
```

You should look into bound parameters for correct SQL injection prevention, as you are wide open as it stands.

Personally, I think your query is failing because your use of string dilemas `'` instead of assigning table names/column names as a table using backticks  (`). So MySQL might be trying to iterate the necessary names as strings instead of table names/columns

Comment: That could work, but you should explain why `NOW()` isn't working.

Comment: it is still inserting all the zeros other than the actual date and time

Comment: @RodrigoLessa not working for new rows or for updates? Or both?

Comment: @Mike ip adress and id are inserted but the datetime is just a bunch of zeros everything else works

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: He's not actually 'wide open', because if anything other than an IP address is passed in to `ip2long()` it returns false so he's more likely to get an SQL syntax error than anything else.  But that's really beside the point - use prepared statements!  What datatype is `dates`?

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly SETting:

```
  INSERT INTO 'u_visits' SET ip_adress = '$ip', dates=NOW() ON ...
```

Also, as someone else mentioned, be absolutely sure $ip has been properly checked, otherwise you're subjecting yourself to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: google "sql injection attacks" and you'll get plenty about this issue :)

Comment: In this case he's actually sanitising it with `ip2long()`, but generally speaking you should be using a prepared statement.